# Can I import from a module based on raw_input, in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7 is it possible to take user input and use this to determine which module gets loaded?

I tried something like:

```
userModule = raw_input("Which module to import? ")
from userModule import *
```

where there is no preexisting module called userModule...

Currently this returns: **ImportError: No module named userModule**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `importlib` module, and a little `globals()` trickery:

```
import importlib

userModule = raw_input("Which module to import? ")

mod = importlib.import_module('signal')
names = mod.__all__ if hasattr(mod, '__all__') else dir(mod)
g = globals()
for name in names:
    g[name] = getattr(mod, name)
del g, name, names, mod, importlib
```

Note how this is not the easiest and most straightforward task, and you may want to rethink the wisdom of doing this.

Comment: Hmmm, I was originally toying with this idea to quickly prototype something...but it's by no means an essential (or even desirable) feature, so I'll stop flogging this dead horse now and go back to doing what I'm supposed to be doing

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the `__import__` function:

```
userModuleName = raw_input("Which module to import? ")
try:
    userModule = __import__(userModuleName)
except ImportError:
    print "could not import", userModuleName
```

Comment: This is not the same as `from modulename import *`, which would import everything provided by `modulename` into the local namespace.

Comment: Ah, fair point.  And well taken.  It's an extra step to take all the stuff in `userModule.__dict__` and put it in globals.  Although, if it can be avoided, I would counsel against `import *` from a module named at runtime.  Importing some module at runtime is nasty enough.  Don't compound it by importing `*`

Comment: I quite agree with that last point, it's not a wise idea to do this *at all*. Yet the script is presumably already being run on a local terminal, so whomever is running it is not going to do anything worse than what they already can do themselves by simply opening up the python interpreter. :-)